# Consulta SQL con Join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

tengo una busqueda de datos correlacionados en tablas. 
El resultado de la búsqueda es una lista donde informa si tenemos o no una vinculación. El Query es: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tabla resultante: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La fila 1 y 2 son lo mismo, solo que en la primera no está vinculado y en la segunda si. 
No debe aparecer la primera, ¿que puedo hacer? Uso SQLyog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

por favor revisa las diferencias entre los LEFT y los INNER JOIN.
Con LEFT traes la Tabla2 con las relaciones de la Tabla1 sin importar si están o no relacionadas.
Con INNER, obligas a que te muestra únicamente la relación entre Tabla1 y Tabla2.
También puedes usar "GROUP BY" Ej:

```
WHERE a.id_equipos = 3 
GROUP BY IdDucto.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya que solo has puesto una imagen te daré el siguiente ejemplo:

```
select * from 
(
select 1 as tusdatos, 1 as columna --Aquí va tu consulta
)t
where columna = 1; --Aquí pondrías Vinculado = 1 o <> de 0
```

Esta es la solución que se me ocurre.